# FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token throwing after upgrading to nodejs 16

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token error is throwing in google-cloud/storage bucket.getFiles() function after upgrading to Nodejs 16.

It works fine with Nodejs 14 and works as well on local macOs machine with Nodejs 16. When the code is being deployed to GKE. It throws this error whenever I try to list bucket files.

Tried Nodejs 18 and 20 as well. The code is not changed while migrating from nodejs 14 to 16. Also tried to upgrade google-cloud/storage library to latest version but still the same result.

I have verified the credentials and there is nothing wrong with it.

I little help would be appreciated!

google-cloud/storage : 5.20.5
Nodejs : 16.16.0

here is the sample code for google-cloud/storage implementation

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const storage = new Storage({
  projectId : 'project_id',
  credentials: {
   client_email: 'your-service-account-email@your-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    private_key: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nYOUR_PRIVATE_KEY\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'
}
});

async function listFiles() {
  try {
   
    const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);

   
    const [files] = await bucket.getFiles();

    console.log('Files:');
    files.forEach(file => {
      console.log(file.name);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error listing files:', err);
    // above mentioned error is being thrown here.
  }
}
```

Complete stack trace

```
FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token: Premature close 
"FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token: Premature close
    at Gunzip.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:400:12)
    at Gunzip.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at Gunzip.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)"
```

Comment: What is this? `credentials: 'google cloud credential object'`. Show the actual code .

Comment: @JohnHanley I have edited the code snippet. It is a credential object with service account and private key.

Comment: What is the result of this code: `const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library'); const auth = new GoogleAuth(); const token = await auth.getAccessToken(); console.log(token);`

Comment: Does the stack trace display the response body?

Comment: @JohnHanley I have added the complete stack trace

Comment: @JohnHanley I tried your code and it is throwing the same error. It works in local but doesn't work after deploying to GKE